# How do I create expandable lists on Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Is there any way to create expandable lists on Titanium? I want the ListItem to expand and show extra info when the user clicks on a dropdown icon, just like in the image below:

[image: expandable list]

I'm not sure if this can be achieved in Titanium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be a Titanium specific question because there are multiple ways to create such a list in any platform, be it Titanium, native Android/iOS or any other platform.

It depends on you which way you prefer. Using ListView, you can simply create a ListView & add ListItems or child-views in a ListItem upon clicking a parent list-item, and do vice-versa on deleting or hiding the content.

You will need to take care about the clicking events when to add/when to delete or hide the content, though it will require lot of coding but it will be worth doing so because then you can understand how things behind the scenes work. It's time taking to provide you a code-base here, so I suggest you to start working on to create this feature or you can take a look here at this sample code - [Expandable ListView](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17440/Appcelerator-Making-an-expandable-accordian-menu.html)